# Looking for help optimizing a Powershell script to parse through a CSV line by line

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a large csv file with 41000 rows of data.  Within this I have to go through and inspect each row for a particular string PRCXX and if the row contains that in column 6 then I take the value of column 10 and replace the value in column 9 with it.

I have code that works however it takes a very long time to parse through line by line.  I am looking for some help to try and optimize it.  I have tried switching to a ForEach loop however I am not sure how exactly to get it to work with what I am trying to accomplish and haven't been able to find any examples to work from.

Here is the code that I have that currently is working just takes along time to complete.

```bsh
Import-Csv $TransFile -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.6 -match "PRCXX") {
    $_.9 = $_.10
    } 
$_ | Export-Csv test2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Delimiter ","
}
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: The most time consumptive is a _disk_ operation. Move  the `| Export-Csv test2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Delimiter ","` out from `ForEach-Object` loop body.

Comment: Wow that fixed it.  Thanks for pointing that out can't believe I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to JosefZ this is fixed.  Moved the Export to occur outside the loop and that cleared it up.

```bsh
Import-Csv $TransFile -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.6 -match "PRCXX") {
    $_.9 = $_.10
    } 
$_ 
} | Export-Csv test2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Delimiter ","
```

Comment: Please consider marking  [your own answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). See [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.